# jQuery plugin: datepicker along with time selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

can some one suggest me jQuery plugin which should be very light weight and highly configurable datetime picker. Time should n't be slectable as sliders (like in jQuery UI).

Iam using "ANYTIME.JS" but it takes a long time in first loading and more than one clicking, gives errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok to assign time seperately, you can use [jQuery UI Timepicker](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timepicker-by-fgelinas).

Answer (score 0):

[jquery.timepicker](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) looks quite good and does not force date part selection.